# Grails createCriteria from mysql query with inner join

Tags: grails

I have this mysql query

```
SELECT cr1.project_id 
FROM contribution_request as cr1
INNER JOIN contribution_request as cr2 ON cr1.project_id = cr2.project_id 
WHERE cr1.instrument_id = 5 AND cr2.instrument_id = 6
```

And I need to execute it via grails `createCriteria` function

I have tried this but it is not working and I cant find how to do it.

```
 def pc = ContributionRequest.createCriteria();
    def Object = pc.list {

        projections {
            property("project.id")
        }

        and {
            eq "instrument.id", 5L
            eq "instrument.id", 6L
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `projections` you should use `get` instead of `list`. Your code would looks like this:

```
 def pc = ContributionRequest.createCriteria();
def Object = pc.get {

    projections {
        property("project.id")
    }

    and {
        eq "instrument.id", 5L
        eq "instrument.id", 6L
    }
}
```